# How to dynamically add and delete JTextField on Label click

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

I Have two labels, one for adding and one for deleting JtextFields. I can add jTextFields and remove them, but my goal is to remove textfields on label click.

The picture below shows my goal, everytime the "+" label is clicked, a textfield below it will be created. And when i click the "-" label the textfields on the same row will be deleted.
what should i do to achieve that?

this is my code:

```
lblRemoveTf = new JLabel();
    lblRemoveTf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            for(JTextField myTxt1 : myListOfTxtNum){
                eto1 = myTxt1;

            }
            myListOfTxtNum.remove(eto1);
            pnlTxtTxt.remove(pnlTxtTxt.getComponentAt(eto1.getLocation()));

            frmGM.revalidate();
            frmGM.repaint();
            for(JTextField myTxt : myListOfTxtName){
                eto = myTxt;

            }
            myListOfTxtName.remove(eto);        
            pnlTxtTxt.remove(pnlTxtTxt.getComponentAt(eto.getLocation()));
            x-=50;
            y-=50;
            frmGM.revalidate();
            frmGM.repaint();


        }
    });
    lblRemoveTf.setBounds(450,6, 125, 25);
    pnlTxtTxt.add(lblRemoveTf);
    lblRemoveTf.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GroupManagement.class.getResource("/app/resources/minussmall.png")));

    lblAddNewTF = new JLabel();
    lblAddNewTF.setBounds(420, 6, 38, 25);
    lblAddNewTF.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


            count++;
            txtStudentName= new JTextField();
            txtStudentNumber = new JTextField();
            myListOfTxtName.add(txtStudentName);
            myListOfTxtNum.add(txtStudentNumber);
            txtStudentName.setName("txtStudentname"+count);
            txtStudentNumber.setName("txtStudentNumber" + count);



            pnlTxtTxt.add(txtStudentName);
            pnlTxtTxt.add(txtStudentNumber);


            doContainTheListsOfTxt(txtStudentName, txtStudentNumber);

            if(count>0){
                x+=50;
                y+=50;

                txtStudentName.setBounds(225,6+y, 182, 27);
                txtStudentNumber.setBounds(35, 6+y, 182, 27);
                txtStudentName.setName(tempBox+count);
                if(pnlTxtTxt.getComponentCount() >9){

                    pnlTxtTxt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450+y,50+y));
                    pnlTxtTxt.add(txtStudName);
                    pnlTxtTxt.add(txtStudentNumber);

                    frmGM.repaint();
                    scrpTxtTxt.revalidate();
                }
            }
            frmGM.repaint();
        }

    });
    lblAddNewTF.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GroupManagement.class.getResource("/app/resources/plussmall.png")));
    pnlTxtTxt.add(lblAddNewTF);
```

and this is the photo i want to achieve

[image: This is the photo]

Comment: `+` and `-` are labels? Why labels have to work like command buttons? You really are wishing for magic ;)

Comment: yes. is that not possible?

Comment: i did it on the first row, i just dont know how to do it on the succeeding labels.

Comment: What not possible when there are magic wands like `Swing`, `multiple classes`, `control over elements`?

Answer (score 5):

1. Don't use a null layout and setBounds(). You can use a vertical BoxLayout to add rows of comonents.
2. Create a class to represent a single row. So you would use a JPanel with two text fields and two buttons.
3. Every time you add a row of panels you add the panel to an ArrayList so you can track each row.
4. When you click on the "-" button you can use the getParent() method to find the panel the button belongs to. Then you can use the Container.remove(...) method to remove the row.
5. When you click on the "+" button you get the parent panel. Then you can search the ArrayList to get the index of the current panel. Then you can use the Container.add(...) method to add the panel to the Container and also add the panel to the ArrayList.

Also, instead of using a JLabel for the buttons, you can use a JButton. You can just use the `setBorderPainted(false)` method and the button will look like a label.